# Laravel-5.8::Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

hi i have multiple db tables ('dealers,suppliers,histories') and trying to show data of suppliers which are related to dealers(in dealers table supplier_id is using as foreign key)at dealers index but it is showing error: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,m trying to get history data form dealers index by supplier id,,,,,,,,,,,,

note only dealers are showing on index and I am using resource route for it

code of index:

```php
@foreach ($data as $row)
  <tr>
    <td>{{ $row->dealer_name }}</td>
    <td>
      @foreach($row->supplier as $sp)
        {{ $sp->supplier_name }}<br>
      @endforeach
    </td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

Controller code:

```php
$data = Dealer::all(); 

return view('dealer.index', compact('data'));
```

supplier model:

```
 public function dealerHistory()
 {
     return $this->hasoneThrough('App\History', 'App\Dealer');
 }
```

all other models only have protected fillable in them  according to this https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#has-one-through

Comment: Are you expecting `$row->supplier` to be an array or other `Iterable`? If you don't know then try inserting `dd($row->supplier);` before the `foreach` containing it. It would be helpful if you would include the full output when asking for help with a code error.

Comment: $data = Dealer::all();
        return view('dealer.index', compact('data'));

Comment: Please can you also edit your question and include the code for your `Dealer` Model.

Comment: editied.....................

Comment: can you show your `Dealer` model

Answer (score 0):

```
@foreach ($data as $row)
  <tr>
    <td>{{ $row->dealer_name }}</td>
    <td>
      @if(!empty($row->supplier()))
        @foreach($row->supplier as $sp)
          {{ $sp->supplier_name }}<br>
        @endforeach
      @endif
    </td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Call to undefined method App\Dealer::supplier()

Answer (score 0):

Here as you mentioned *dealers are showing* then problem must be in `@foreach($row->supplier as $sp)`

As error says Invalid argument supplied for foreach() you need to verify `$row->supplier` is array.

```
@foreach ($data as $row)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $row->dealer_name }}</td>
        <td>
            @if(is_array($row->supplier) && !empty($row->supplier))
                @foreach($row->supplier as $sp)
                {{ $sp->supplier_name }}<br>
                @endforeach
            @endif
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: @dev what is in $data? paste here

Comment: public function index()
    {
        $data = Dealer::all();
        return view('dealer.index', compact('data'));
    }

Comment: m following this tutorial https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#has-one-through

Comment: its only returning the dealer data i wants supplier names related to dealer